# Is creation of new instance in subclass always necessary to use the attributes from the super class?

Tags: oop, inheritance, attributes, python-3.6

for the below code snippet

```
class CreditCard:
   def __init__(self,customer,bank,acnt,limit):
    ....
    ....
class PredatoryCreditCard(CreditCard):
   def__init__(self,customer,bank,acnt,limit):
   ....
   super().__init__(customer,bank,acnt,limit)
```

1. Is it always necessary to write `def__init__(self,customer,bank,acnt,limit):` in subclass? Or the `super().__init__(customer,bank,acnt,limit)` will do the work?
2. If there's another new parameter `newattr` used in the subclass, then should it be included in the `__init__()` method or declaring using `self._newattr= newattr` would suffice?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your subclass defines an `__init__` method, it will inherit the `__init__` method of it's parent.  So there's no difference between

```
class A(Parent):
    def __init__(self,customer,bank,acnt,limit):
        super().__init__(customer, bank, acnt, limit)
```

and

```
class A(Parent):
    pass
```

You only need to override the `__init__` method with your own implementation if you need to do specific configuration for instances of that class.

```
class PredatoryCreditCard(CreditCard):
    def __init__(self,customer, bank, acnt, limit, newattr):
        super().__init__(customer, bank, acnt, limit) 
        self._newattr = newattr
```

All of the setup of instance-specific attributes should occur in the `__init__` method.

This inheritance behaviour doesn't treat `__init__` differently from any other method.

Comment: Suppose if i write :   class A(Parent):\n   super().__ init__(customer,bank,act,limit) without pre-defining def__init__( customer,bank,act,limit) ,does it pass all the parameters of the parent?

Comment: Can you please recommend me sources to practice python oops from beginner to advanced.